# Buy hours from heroku

Tags: heroku

I was wondering, i host my discord bot with heroku, and got 550 hours free each month. 550 hours is not enough for the whole month. I don't have a creditcard, so the additional 450 hours are out of my range. I had a question, is it possible to buy the other 200 hours?

greetings, Bas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to buy hours in that way. Free dynos are "charged" completely differently than paid dynos. If you need more hours than you have available in your free dyno pool, you'll need to upgrade to paid dynos to keep them running.

I wrote a full guide on [how Heroku free dynos work](https://railsautoscale.com/heroku-free-dynos) that might help if any of this is still unclear.